# What correct architecture of qml dynamic widgets?

Tags: qt, qml

Its very hard to formulate question. But look on the followind picture:
[image]

For example there are exists list widget which items dynammically change content when receive hover state. For simplicity item contents depends on some set of bool values.

With QWidgets its easy could be achieved by checking the bool values when some signal raised and show/hide dependent components.

But how it could achieved with qml?

As I understand correctly the qml gui - its kind of "static" GUI and I should have different gui set to switch. But in described example I receive the combinatorial explosion.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I got your question right, but let's begin from examples

```
 ListModel {
    id: listModel

    ListElement {
        name: "John"
        age: 32
        gender: "male"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Kate"
        age: 23
        gender: "female"
    }
}

ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent

    model: listModel
    spacing: 5

    delegate: Rectangle {
        color: "#24F5F2"

        width: parent.width
        height: 50

        Text {
            id: nameText
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            text: name
        }

        Text {
            id: ageOrGenderText
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            text: gender
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true

            onEntered: {
                ageOrGenderText.text = age
            }

            onExited: {
                ageOrGenderText.text = gender
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you can create a separate boolean property and set it on entered/exited to true/false and do a QML binding to this property

```
property bool hovered: false

Text {
    id: textItem
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    text: hovered ? "age" : "gender" // or CppBackend.GetValue(hovered)
}

MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    hoverEnabled: true

    onEntered: {
        textItem = true;
    }

    onExited: {
        textItem = false;
    }
}
```